# Android Index out of bounds

Tags: android, indexing, webrequest, bounds, out

I am trying to get the **bold** text next to the hour scheldule ( from http://golfnews.no/golfpaatv.php )put it in a String array , then , show it on my device's screen. I've put the Internet Access permission , so that is not the problem.The application crashes on my device . Reason : index out of bounds . I don't understand where's the problem . My code is :

```
package com.work.webrequest;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebRequest extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String trax;

        String aux[] = new String[10];

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        trax=getPage();

       aux= title (trax);


       txt.setText(" Here I will display every title!!!");

    }
    private String[] title (String trax)
    {

        String result[] = new String[10];
        int ok=1;
        int s1,s2;
        int i=0;
        while(ok==1)
        {
            System.out.println("INDEX = "+trax.indexOf("<h2>"));
            ok=0;
            if(trax.indexOf("<h2>")!=-1)
            {


            ok=1;
            s1 =trax.indexOf("<h2>");
            s2 = trax.indexOf("</h2>");
            result[i] = trax.substring(s1+4,s2);
            i++;
            trax = trax.substring(trax.indexOf("</h2>"));

            }

        }
         return result;
    }

    private String getPage() {
        String str = "***";

        try
        {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.golfnews.no/feed.php?feed=1");
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

            if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                str = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        return str;
    }


}
```

The number of `<h2>` and `</h2>` is below 10 . My application crashes at the 2nd iteration . I am a beginner in android , so I don't know much  . Could you give me a hint ? I would really appreciate it . Thank you !

**PS : I know what Index Out of bounds means , I just don't know why I get the error here .**

Comment: You say there is an IndexOutOfBoundsException; could you show the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you want to access an array index which is out of range. For example:

```
String[] myArray = new String[10];
myArray[10] = "test"; // 10 is out of limits(0-9)
```

Would produce such an exception. Check the stacktrace for the line that this exception originates from. It tells you the class name/method name/line number that this problem comes from.

In your case I suspect there are more than 10 `<h2>` in the `trax`, so you get this exception.

Initially you don't know the number of `<h2>`'s so change this line:

```
String result[] = new String[10];
```

with this:

```
ArrayList<String> result= new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you can add elements to this list with the following:

```
// result[i] = trax.substring(s1+4,s2);
result.add(trax.substring(s1+4,s2));
```

**EDIT1**
Also I think you mean this:

```
//trax = trax.substring(trax.indexOf("</h2>"));
trax = trax.substring(s2 + 5);
```

**EDIT2**

Also I realized you allocate arrays wrong, you are allocating a String of 10 chars instead of an array of 10 Strings:

```
//String aux[] = new String[10];
String[] aux = new String[10];

//String result[] = new String[10];
String[] result = new String[10];
```

Comment: +1 for "Check the stacktrace for the line that this exception originates from".

Comment: I know this , the thing that I don't know is why in this application,even if I write 'String result[] = new String[20]' , I get the same error . The number of titles from that page is below 10 .

Comment: The number of <h2> and </h2> is below 10 . My application crashes at the 2nd iteration .

Comment: I've made those changes and still , my application crashes at the same ( 2nd) iteration

Comment: Done , `trax = trax.substring(trax.indexOf("</h2>") + 5);` , now , the application crashes at the 1st iteration

Comment: @George print out `s1`, `s2`, & `trax.length()` before `result.add(trax.substring(s1+4,s2));` and check if there is anything funny

Comment: @George it means that after 1st iteration you don't proceed forward to correct location, so this is wrong: `trax.substring(trax.indexOf("</h2>"));` and at 2nd iteration, `</h2>` is at the beginning. Did you try to add +5 like I mentioned?

Comment: With the `+5` the application crashes after the 1st iteration

Comment: how could this be ? If you look here : [link](view-source:http://golfnews.no/golfpaatv.php) you'll see that there are 10 `</h2>`

Comment: Check edit2, this is why it crashes after the 1st time when you add +5. So do both edit1 & edit2 and should work. Even better replace `String[]` with `ArrayList`

Comment: Thank you ! Now it works ! I got only one question :  how can I put the `ArrayList<String>` in the `TextView` ? more precise ... How can I access each member of the `ArrayList` ?

Comment: `result.get(i)` returns you the ith `String` in the `ArrayList`, and `result.size()` gives you the number of elements in the `ArrayList`, example: `for(int i =0; i <  results.size(); i++){ String s = results.get(i);}`

Comment: Than you very much ! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this one too..

```
if(trax.indexOf("<h2>")!=-1&&i<10)
            {


            ok=1;
            s1 =trax.indexOf("<h2>");
            s2 = trax.indexOf("</h2>");
            result[i] = trax.substring(s1+4,s2);
            i++;
            trax = trax.substring(trax.indexOf("</h2>"));

            }
```